# How to use radio buttons instead of check boxes

Tags: html, css, list, checkbox, radio-button

I have a menu that has "whats new" and "categories" when you press categories there are 3 categories that drop down. And when you press each of those 3 categories they have sub menus. My question is how can I make it so that if a category is clicked the previous category disappears. (for example if I had category 1 open and then I clicked category 2, the menu for category 1 would close up) I was suggested to use radio buttons, however I tried replacing all checkbox's with radio's and it did not work. Does anyone have any solutions? Thanks in advance. Here is a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/fgkusnt9/

```html
<div class='shop-sidebar'>
  <ul class='shop-nav'>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">What's New</a></li>
    <li class='w-sub' data-id='shop-categories'>
      <svg class='s_arrow_down'><use xlink:href="#s_arrow_down"></use></svg>
      <input type="checkbox" id="categories" />
      <label id="label" for="categories">Categories</label>
      <ul id="subList">
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="all" />
          <label id="allLabel" for="all">All</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="category1" />
          <label id="category1Label" for="category1">Category 1</label>
          <ul id="subListCategory1">
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 9</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="category2" />
          <label id="category2Label" for="category2">Category 2</label>
          <ul id="subListCategory2">
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="category3" />
          <label id="category3Label" for="category3">Category 3</label>
          <ul id="subListCategory3">
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 1</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

css

```css
.shop-sidebar {
width: 30%;
width: calc(295px);
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 65px;
vertical-align: top;
font-family: 'maison',sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 11px;
color: #000;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
line-height: 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul.shop-nav {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
ul.shop-nav li.active, ul.shop-nav li:hover {
color: #000;
opacity: 1;
font-weight: bold;
}
ul.shop-nav li {
transition: all 0.3s;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px 20px;
background-color: #f8f8f8;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}
ul.shop-nav li.active a {
color: #000;
}
ul.shop-nav a {
color: #000;
}
ul.shop-nav li.active, ul.shop-nav li:hover {
color: #000;
opacity: 1;
font-weight: bold;
}
ul.shop-nav li svg {
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
vertical-align: text-bottom;
fill: #000;
transition: all 0.3s;
float: right;
}
ul.shop-nav li ul {
display: none;
list-style: none;
padding-left: 0;
margin: 12px 0 0;
}
ul.shop-nav li ul li {
color: #000;
border: 0 !important;
font-family: 'maison',sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
letter-spacing: 0;
padding: 0;
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: none;
margin-bottom: 12px;
}
ul.shop-nav li ul ul {
margin-left: 16px;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

#subList, 
#subListCategory1,
#subListCategory2,
#subListCategory3 {
  display: none;
}

#categories:checked ~ #subList {
  display: block;
}

#category1:checked ~ #subListCategory1 {
  display: block;
}

#category2:checked ~ #subListCategory2 {
  display: block;
}

#category3:checked ~ #subListCategory3 {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the checkbox to radio button and give all radio button the same name attribute. This will make them a single group and at a time a single radio will be checked.

```
     <ul id="subList">
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="all" />
          <label id="allLabel" for="all">All</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name= "category"  id="category1" />
          <label id="category1Label" for="category1">Category 1</label>
          <ul id="subListCategory1">
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 9</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name= "category"  id="category2" />
          <label id="category2Label" for="category2">Category 2</label>
          <ul id="subListCategory2">
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name= "category" id="category3" />
          <label id="category3Label" for="category3">Category 3</label>
          <ul id="subListCategory3">
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 1</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>

  </ul>
```

Additionally add the css to hide radio,

```
input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
.shop-sidebar {
width: 30%;
width: calc(295px);
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 65px;
vertical-align: top;
font-family: 'maison',sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 11px;
color: #000;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
line-height: 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul.shop-nav {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
ul.shop-nav li.active, ul.shop-nav li:hover {
color: #000;
opacity: 1;
font-weight: bold;
}
ul.shop-nav li {
transition: all 0.3s;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px 20px;
background-color: #f8f8f8;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}
ul.shop-nav li.active a {
color: #000;
}
ul.shop-nav a {
color: #000;
}
ul.shop-nav li.active, ul.shop-nav li:hover {
color: #000;
opacity: 1;
font-weight: bold;
}
ul.shop-nav li svg {
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
vertical-align: text-bottom;
fill: #000;
transition: all 0.3s;
float: right;
}
ul.shop-nav li ul {
display: none;
list-style: none;
padding-left: 0;
margin: 12px 0 0;
}
ul.shop-nav li ul li {
color: #000;
border: 0 !important;
font-family: 'maison',sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
letter-spacing: 0;
padding: 0;
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: none;
margin-bottom: 12px;
}
ul.shop-nav li ul ul {
margin-left: 16px;
}

input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

#subList, 
#subListCategory1,
#subListCategory2,
#subListCategory3 {
  display: none;
}

#categories:checked ~ #subList {
  display: block;
}

#category1:checked ~ #subListCategory1 {
  display: block;
}

#category2:checked ~ #subListCategory2 {
  display: block;
}

#category3:checked ~ #subListCategory3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='shop-sidebar'>
  <ul class='shop-nav'>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">What's New</a></li>
    <li class='w-sub' data-id='shop-categories'>
      <svg class='s_arrow_down'><use xlink:href="#s_arrow_down"></use></svg>
      <input type="checkbox" id="categories" />
      <label id="label" for="categories">Categories</label>
      <ul id="subList">
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="all" />
          <label id="allLabel" for="all">All</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name= "category"  id="category1" />
          <label id="category1Label" for="category1">Category 1</label>
          <ul id="subListCategory1">
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 9</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name= "category"  id="category2" />
          <label id="category2Label" for="category2">Category 2</label>
          <ul id="subListCategory2">
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name= "category" id="category3" />
          <label id="category3Label" for="category3">Category 3</label>
          <ul id="subListCategory3">
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Category 1</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/num6t3x6/

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @user6738171 NP :) glad to help

Comment: I also have a question if your willing to help. In the attached fiddle you can see I added cursor:pointer for hover state. So that when a user hovers over any of the links it will turn to the hand. Everything changed to the pointer except for the sub categories (Category 1,2 and 3) Do you know why this is? - https://jsfiddle.net/num6t3x6/2/

Comment: @user6738171 you can assign pointer cursor css on the label tag. https://jsfiddle.net/grnaL0x2/